# How to implement omniauth, healthgraph and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, omniauth

I'm trying to build a very simple Rails app where people can log in and then see a list of their Run Keeper Fitness Activities

I opted to use Devise and OmniAuth to handle the logins (complete with omniauth-runkeeper).  All was working well, having followed Ryan Bates brilliant Railscast on the topic.

I was then keen to use the [HealthGraph gem](https://github.com/kennyma/health_graph) to connect to the RunKeeper API. To do so, it needs an access token.  I opted to pull this at point of authorising the app, and record it in the user model (as outlined in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/3405032)) but I'm not sure this approach is quite right.  Should I be recording this access token permanently in the database?  I can easily create a new connection through the API now by using the following, but I'm concerned that this isn't the securest approach.

```
@user = HealthGraph::User.new(current_user.run_token)
```

Any advice or tips on a different approach would be greatly appreciated.

Ian

Comment: I noticed you didn't get a response in your [Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/healthgraph/wPi6xCNOUlk/discussion), either. Have you just gone forward with storing the token, or have you found another way about this?

Comment: I ended up storing in the database, creating a separate table for all the different types of Authentications the Users might create.